# <ul> <li> positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating an image gallery where there are 9 list items per slide but with only 1 unordered list. The reason I am doing it this way so the content can be easily added into the CMS rather than having to add a new unordered list everytime they wish to add a gallery.

The way that the code is set up is:

```
<div class="gallery">
<span class="prv_button"><a href=""></a></span>
<div class="gallery_wrap">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<span class="nxt_button"><a href=""></a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

At the moment the unordered list does not have a width as it needs to be able to scroll to the next set of list item but at the moment there displaying inline next to each other. However I want to display underneath one another in 3's. I have tried setting a height on the unoreder list but that does not make a different because of the width of the unordered list.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Use CSS display property.
Here is a demo [Display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=list-item)

Comment: It's not as simple as that! Trust me i've tried :P but thanks

Comment: I think you need something like this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/y46wb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first ideas to solve this are CSS selectors like:

```
/* quick & dirty */
ul li:nth-child(3n):after {
    content: '<br />';
}
```

OR

```
ul li {
    float: left;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    display: block !important;
}
```

This should position the 1st, 4th, 7th, ... list item (i.e. picture) to the very left with three pictures in a row.

You could also try to put fixed widths so that the elements have got to obey:

```
ul {
    width: 650px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Let me know when there's something odd with the code or if I misunderstood your question, I'll try to fix it accordingly.

Comment: Ok not really getting much luck with that but thanks for your reply.. Here is the CSS i am using and the CSS i added that you gave me. I could be doing something totally wrong. You will have to copy the css out..Not sure how to add the CSS. - .gallery ul{
 margin:0px !important;
 margin-left:17px !important;
 padding:0xp !important;
 height:225px;
 width:10000px; 
}

.gallery ul li{
 list-style-type:none !important;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 margin-bottom:1px;
 float:left;
 display:inline-block !important;
}

.gallery ul li:nth-child(3n+1): {
    display: block !important;
}

Comment: So you wanna scroll to the right? I still don't get the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't set a width to the <ul> becuase the Jquery auto assigns with width depending on how many slides there are. This helps the slider scroll without any issues.

Comment: Sorry.. Yes i want to scroll to the right but i want all 9 list items to scroll to ANOTHER 9 list items. I want it to be all in 1 <ul> as the data is being added through a CMS system. The <ul> can't have a set width because the Jquery sets the width depending on how many <li> there are.

At the moment the <li> are all displaying next to each other in a line from left to right meaning even if i have 12 slides you will only see 6 <li> but i want to see 9 and then anymore to go onto the next slide and so on..

Comment: Ah, if you're going to scroll to the right then my post makes completely no sense. I guess you are using the wrong jQuery slider plugin for your situation, then... Edit your starting post to describe the issue as good as possible (with screenshots of what it looks like now and what it is _supposed_ to look like), so I can help you later.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this
 `.prv_button,.nxt_button,.gallery_wrap ul{floal:left;}
.gallery_wrap ul li{float:left;}
.gallery_wrap ul{width: ulWidth; height:ulWidth; overflow:hidden;}`